# Can CRAN packages be modified and re-uploaded by others?

Tags: r, package, cran

I've been working with R for a long time, but I'm a complete newbie in writing (and/or publishing) own packages via CRAN. Actually, I create a new package for educational purposes (university) and I want to load it to CRAN, so my students (and, of course, others) can download and use it.

After I uploaded my package (let's call it “JohnnyStat”), is it possible that another person (let's call “Mark Miller”) modifies it and adds his name as another “co-author” (“author”/“contributor” etc.)?

So, as a result, the package “JohnnyStat” would be registered as written by “Johnny” AND “Mark Miller”?

Answer (score 1):

No. Only the maintainer can upload package updates, not any co-author. An acceptance mail is automatically sent to the mail address of the maintainer. And no-one can become maintainer without the explicit consent of the previous maintainer (for obvious reasons).

If you want the possibility of various people modifying the package, maybe CRAN is not the best option. It is possible to install from other repositories. Why not have the package at e.g. R-forge or github?

You may get a more complete answer if you ask this on [the CRAN mailing list R-package-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-package-devel).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!